# gcc wont compile and run MySQL C libraries

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference, mysql

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
}
```

> ~$ gcc -o mysql-test MySQL-Test.c

im trying to execute this test program from terminal but get the following error message:

/tmp/cceEmI0I.o: In function `main': MySQL-Test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to`mysql_get_client_info'

what is wrong? my system is ubuntu

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MySQL` comes with a special script called `mysql_config`. It provides you with useful information for compiling your MySQL client and connecting it to MySQL database server.

Pass `--libs` option - Libraries and options required to link with the MySQL client library.

```
$ mysql_config --libs
```

Typical Output:

```
-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto
```

Now you can add this to your compile/link line:

```
gcc -o mysql-test MySQL-Test.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

Comment: thanks that script helped clear up afew things, the following works just fine:

"gcc -o mysql-test MySQL-Test.c -lmysqlclient" 


now that the test class is working, how would i port that command to an IDE such as NetBeans?

Comment: I'd suggest writing a Makefile which will take care of compiling the application automatically. In there you can specify the command line arguments for GCC. 
You can find information on how to write makefiles here: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/larger/makefiles.html  
There are load of websites to help you writing your own makefile.

Comment: @codaddict How would you do this in windows?

Answer (score 4):

You need `gcc -o mysql-test MySQL-Test.c -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lz`

Replace `-L/usr/local/mysql/lib` with wherever you client library is (if it isn't already in your libpath)

See the MySql [instructions for building clients](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/building-clients.html).

Answer (score 3):

For uses of Netbeans on Linux

Open you make file (MakeFile) and add the following lines

```
# These are the flags that gcc requires in order to link correctly against our installed 
# client packages
MYSQL_LIBS := $(shell mysql_config --libs)
```

right below the Environment block.

Then right click on your project node , select Properties, Build  and add `$(MYSQL_LIBS)` to the Additional options parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking to the libraries. Use: `gcc -llibrarygoeshere -o mysql-test MySQL-Test.c`
See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) for more information about linking with gcc.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a compilation error. It is a link error.

Add the mysql library to create your executable with option `-lmysql` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to link against the MySQL library.
Try adding `-lmysql` to your compilation line.

See http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but worked for me
If you are using an IDE you should link the library to your project.
I am using `CodeBlocks` on ubuntu 12.4 64x.  For linking the library, you should go to Project -> Build options -> linker settings and add the library. this is my lib path : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so`

Hope be useful...