# How to setup Netbeans for MySQL programming in C

Tags: mysql, c, linux, netbeans, compilation

I am trying to develop an application in C in a target Linux system which requires Mysql Conectivity but i dont know where to include in NETBEANS the required directives for the libmysqlclient-dev library.

I have the following:

1. A laptop with `NETBEANS IDE 8.0.2` and remote build host setup.
2. A remote `Ubuntu linux` target which is the remote build host for netbeans.
3. `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` in the Ubuntu Target
4. `mysql_config --libs` gives:

> -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl

5. `mysql_config --libs` gives:

> -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl

According to the [Mysql C Api Building](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html) I have to include the following:

```
gcc -c `mysql_config --cflags` progname.c

gcc -o progname progname.o `mysql_config --libs`
```

Although I am able to build my program manually in the target system, I am not sure where to add the above information in Netbeans.

P.S.1 at the momment my Netbeans build command looks like this:

```
gcc -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/arguments_1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/args.o
```

P.S.2 Please be gentle. I am a newbie with Netbeans, Remote builds, C and Linux development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have managed to get it working.

First I needed to include the Mysql Library paths to the Netbeans makefile as per this post:
[gcc wont compile and run MySQL C libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421033/2824050)

> ```
> # These are the flags that gcc requires in order to link correctly against our installed 
> # client packages
> MYSQL_LIBS := $(shell mysql_config --cflags --libs)
> ```

Then right click on my project node , select Properties->Build->Linker->Compilation Line->Additional Options and add $(MYSQL_LIBS) to the Additional options parameter.

My problem was that I was adding it into the C compiler Additional options parameter.

But this post helped to clarify the order:
[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6717376/2824050)

So now my Netbeans gcc command looks like:

```
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/args.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/args.o src/args.c
gcc     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/arguments_1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/args.o  -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing    -g -DNDEBUG -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl
```

Thank you [Lumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269126/lumi), [Thanassis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542990/thanassis)

Comment: Hi, i am having the same problem as you were, but i dont understand what you did on the second part to make it work, i get an error saying `fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory` can you help me a bit? cheers

Comment: Hello. First you need to edit the Netbeans _makefile_ (as per above) and then you need to add the variable in the **ProjectProperties->Build->Linker->Compilation Line->Additional Options** as per the following:
`$(MYSQL_LIBS) -I/usr/include/libssh -lssh`.